# cannot get node by using selectSingleNode method

Tags: c#, xml

my xml file is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<UpdateInboundim613Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" status="SUCCESS" message="Success" schemaRevisionDate="2016-07-19" schemaRevisionLevel="0" returnCode="0" xmlns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7">
    <model>
        <keys>
            <TransactionID type="String">E-InHPSXIM1089779</TransactionID>
        </keys>
        <instance uniquequery="TransactionID=&quot;E-InHPSXIM1089779&quot;" recordid="E-InHPSXIM1089779">
            <TransactionDetailedTrace xsi:nil="true" />
            <TransactionMessage type="Array">
                <TransactionMessage type="String" />
            </TransactionMessage>
            <OVSCSolutionDescription type="Array">
                <OVSCSolutionDescription type="String">Issue: EL-BANK OUTSIDE WAREHOUSE EGYPT IMEA[2702]Interface[[E1 0/0/0]]|Router|ELBKCE1GW /pg-h-pg1252-256675160|143.34.213.18|Down Solution: As per update from Mai Shrief that the site has been suspended on 30th June. So no need of any investigation. Resolved By: BT NOC</OVSCSolutionDescription>
            </OVSCSolutionDescription>
            <OVSCTicketID type="String">E-IM004004076</OVSCTicketID>
            <RIMSImpact xsi:nil="true" />
            <attachments />
        </instance>
    </model>
    <messages>
        <message type="String" xmlns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7/Common">TransactionStatusDetail in $L.file is:IM Ticket: E-IM004004076 is valid for Update Subtype: Resolve</message>
    </messages>
</UpdateInboundim613Response>
```

but my code cannot get value of element "OVSCTicketID":

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\zzx\Project\SM\R5.1\Harness\InBound.xml");
        XmlNode sigNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/UpdateInboundim613Response/model/instance/OVSCTicketID");
        if (sigNode != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sigNode.InnerText);
        }
```

can you please tell me what's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: the sigNode is always null, I don't know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Xml document uses the default namespace "http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7". You need to use the XmlNamespaceManager to select that node under this namespace.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\zzx\Project\SM\R5.1\Harness\InBound.xml");
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7");
XmlNode sigNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:UpdateInboundim613Response//ns:model//ns:instance//ns:OVSCTicketID",namespaceManager);
if (sigNode != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sigNode.InnerText);
}
```

Above code should work fine.

Comment: so, how to identify the default namespace, or how do you know the default namespace is "http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" ?

Comment: Actually it is very easy to identify default namespace in xml just search for xmlns attribute in root element.

Comment: so, in the root element, I can see this definition: xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", is this a namespace definition?
and I can see some element like this : <RIMSImpact xsi:nil="true" />, I don't know what's the meaning of  xsi:nil, can you explain above 2 questions? thanks

Comment: If any node start with something like xsi:nil or ns:NodeName then meaning of this is that node comes under the namespace(here xsi or ns is just the alias for the namespace).

Comment: I would suggest you to go though these articles for better understanding- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XNamespace defaultNs = ((XElement)doc.FirstNode).GetDefaultNamespace();
            string ovsCTicketID = (string)doc.Descendants(defaultNs + "OVSCTicketID").FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```